# simple .htaccess redirect : how to redirect with parameters?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My goal is simply to redirect:

`/jsn.php?parameters` to `http://www.site2.com/jsn.php?parameters`

I tried with

```
Redirect permanent /jsn.php(.)* http://www.site2.com/jsn.php$1
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Query string parameters are automatically passed, you simply want to do this:

```
Redirect permanent /jsn.php http://www.site2.com/jsn.php
```

The `(.)*` doesn't work with the `Redirect` directive, you were probably thinking of `RedirectMatch`, but either way, you don't need it. And also `(.)*` should be `(.*)`, otherwise the **$1** backreference would only get the first character.

Answer (score 3):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(jsn\.php)$ http://www.site2.com/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an explicit URL rewrite in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^/jsn\.php\?(.*) http://www.site2.com/jsn.php?$1 [R]
```

**Note:** You need to escape . and ? because they are also regular expression characters.

If you have a problem using `mod_rewrite`, post the contents of your file.