# How to change permalinks format in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, permalinks

Sorry if my question was basic or stupid. Please help me how to do this thing i m new to wordpress.

I have permalinks for pagination page like this

```
www.website.com/customtaxonomy.html/1
www.website.com/customtaxonomy.html/2
```

but i need to change this permalinks as

```
www.website.com/customtaxonomy.html?page=1
www.website.com/customtaxonomy.html?page=2
```

only for paginations pages.

Answer (score 1):

I cant comment as I need 50 rep. I believe that you will need a custom function for this, maybe this will help: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57070/change-the-page-slug-in-pagination - its not directly the same but might help you figure it out. The only other thing I can suggest is a rewrite with the .htaccess file. Give this a ganders: [simple .htaccess redirect : how to redirect with parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745977/simple-htaccess-redirect-how-to-redirect-with-parameters)