# Htaccess with 2 different url parameters?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

This is my current `.htaccess` it redirects requests like domain.com/name
to domain.com/art.php?name.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule   ^(.*) art.php?$1 [L]
```

Now I want to redirect domain.com/name/**pay** to domain.com/pay.php?**name**
How can I add this to my current htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 regex capture groups "(.+)" seperated by a / to capture  2 parts  of the uri :

```
RewriteEngine on

#--Don't rewrite real files and directories--#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#--Rewrite everything else to /art.php--#
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/(.+)$ pay.php?$1=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thats not what I want to do, if there is /name/pay I want to redirect it to pay.php

Comment: @User77431 ok, I changed the target url.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this posts:

- [simple .htaccess redirect : how to redirect with parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745977/simple-htaccess-redirect-how-to-redirect-with-parameters)
- [Apache Redirect 301 fails when using GET parameters, such as ?blah=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260632/apache-redirect-301-fails-when-using-get-parameters-such-as-blah)
- And this answer https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/63595

I think this is some helpfull information to understand htaccess.

Comment: Surely this should be in the comments? Technically, it is not an answer to the question...