# Redirect and keep the parameter in the url on .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

It should probably be an easy setup, but without familiarity with the terms used, I can't come up with a solution. I tried several examples that I found on the internet.

I just wanted that when the user accessed the site via a url `https://example.com?foo=bar` he would be directed to `https://www.example.com/new-nice-page?foo=bar`

Changing the page and keeping the parameter.

The last thing I tested:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^https://www.example.com/new-nice-page?foo=$ example.com?foo=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: Another test I just did:

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^https://example.com?foo=$ $1/new-nice-page?foo=$2 [R=301,L]

It should be worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this redirect rule at the top of .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)foo= [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /new-nice-page [L,R=301]
```

Note that query string is automatically carried forward to target URL.

Comment: Looks great. I'll test this one. Thanks, anubhava.

Comment: Sorry for delay. But I forgot to come back. This works for my issue. :)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this thread : [simple .htaccess redirect : how to redirect with parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745977/simple-htaccess-redirect-how-to-redirect-with-parameters)

you simply redirect , without worying about the parameters, because they are automatically passed :
`Redirect permanent /jsn.php http://www.site2.com/jsn.php`

Comment: really? man! I'll test it right now. if it works, I'll be back to let you know. :)

Comment: I don't think it worked. It should only redirect if url have the parameter "foo", if not, it will redirect everything to new page.

Comment: I'm sure what you want. Is this what you observe, or the behaviour that you want ?

Comment: It's just that if I do it this way, it will always redirect, and I just need to redirect when there is the "foo" parameter, and go to the same site, only on another page keeping this parameter.