# Can't pass parameters to another redirect website

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, cpanel

I want to redirect to another website, and pass the parameters also.
Example: I go to my website: `source.example/?code=12345`
Then, I want it to redirect to `target.example/?code=12345`.

I am currently using this for my `.htaccess` file, since I figured out from other posts that if I query a certain parameter, it will get passed also:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^code=[NS]$
RewriteRule "www.google.com" /$1 [R=302,L]
```

Also, I tried many different approaches looking at these stack questions:

- [simple .htaccess redirect : how to redirect with parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745977/simple-htaccess-redirect-how-to-redirect-with-parameters)
- [Redirect and keep the parameter in the url on .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61530406/redirect-and-keep-the-parameter-in-the-url-on-htaccess)

But I can't get it running :(

Comment: You state that you "can't pass parameters", but the directives you've posted wouldn't do anything?

Answer (score 0):

> since I figured out from other posts that if I query a certain parameter, it will get passed also

This is not true. The query string is passed through by default - there is nothing extra you need to do if you want the same query string on the target URL.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^code=[NS]$
> RewriteRule "www.google.com" /$1 [R=302,L]
> ```

This code won't match the source URL for many reasons:

- `"www.google.com"` - The first argument to the `RewriteRule` directive is a regex that matches the source URL-path (less the slash prefix). In your example the URL-path is *empty*.
- `^code=[NS]$` matches either `code=N` or `code=S` - which is not the intention from your example. (The `[NS]` looks like a mangled `RewriteRule` *flag*?!)
- `/$1` - this is the *substitition* string, ie. the URL you want to redirect to. (The `$1` backreference is always empty, so this is meaningless.)

To redirect from `source.example/?code=<number>` to `https://target.example/?code=<number>` then try the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^source\.example [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^code=\d+$
RewriteRule ^$ https://target.example/ [R=302,L]
```

This only matches a query string of the form `code=1234`. It does not match `code=` or `code=1234&foo=bar`, etc.

The query string is passed through by default.

If `source.example` is the only domain being hosted at the current location then you can remove the first *condition* that explicitly checks the requested hostname.

The order of directives in the `.htaccess` file is important. An external redirect like this should go near the top.