URL variable/value doesn't get picked up by php
I have this code to create a new OrdID if no value for this variable exists:
If ($OrdID=="")
{
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","xxx","xxx");
mysql_select_db("xxx_Order", $con);
$query=mysql_query("Select Max(OrdID) FROM `Order`");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
$OrdID= $row[0] + 1;
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO `xxx_Order`.`Order` (`OrdID`) VALUES ($OrdID);"; 
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_close($con);
}

Of course before the above code I have(and I tried to place below code first line of my php file, in the head section and in the body section and also tried $_GET instead of $_REQUEST:
$OrdID=$_REQUEST["OrdID"];

But when I copy/paste following link in the browser the variable/value doesn't get picked up and above code creates a new OrdID:
example.com/test.htm?OrdID=304819
What am I missing? Thanks
Tried $_GET instead of $_REQUEST. Placed code at different sections
Update: Actually I think I know the problem...its my htaccess redirect of:
RewriteRule link--(.*)\--(.*)\--(.*)\--(.*)\--(.*)\.htm$ example.php?Vendor=$1&Maincategory=$2&Source=$3&Pos=$4&Search=$5

Why I think it is the above redirect is because no matter what I add at the end of example.com/test.htm it will always redirect to:
example.php?Vendor=$1&Maincategory=$2&Source=$3&Pos=$4&Search=$5


Why are you using the obsolete mysql_ code library? Its development was discontinued in PHP 5.5 (2013) and removed entirely in PHP 7 (2015). No apps should still be using it. It leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (due to the lack of parameterised query support) and potentially other unpatched vulnerabilities. Switch to using mysqli or PDO (both released in the 2000s!) as soon as possible, and learn how to write parameterised queries to protect your data. See http://bobby-tables.com for a simple explanation of the risks and some sample PHP code to write queries safely.

Also, if you are running mysql_ queries successfully, it shows you are running a very old, unsupported version of PHP. You should upgrade your PHP version urgently to continue to receive security updates. https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php . The last version of PHP (5.6) to include the mysql_ functions went out of support in 2018 (see https://www.php.net/eol.php).

P.S. You're going to need this, very shortly: How to change mysql to mysqli?. Or you might want to consider going to PDO instead.

its my htaccess redirect...so what is happening with that? Is it not redirecting you correctly? What URL is it sending your browser to? Please clarify the behaviour you're seeing. As far as I can see though, it'll redirect you to example.php, but it does not include the OrdID parameter in the new URL, so obviously PHP isn't going to be able to read that. You need to change the htaccess rule so it transfers the OrdID from the first URL to the rewritten one

Ok. So is there anything specific which is preventing you from making that change? Have you tried to do it?

Thanks, I'm actually just trying right now...again very rusty...haven't looked at my htaccess for a while and just tried what kalaivanan wrote at the top of that answer but didn't work

Well if you look at it, kalaivanan's suggestion doesn't involve an OrdID parameter in the redirected URL, so it isn't surprising that it doesn't help! In fact it's almost an exact copy of what you wrote. They seem to have added [L] but haven't bothered to explain why. I'm not a htaccess expert so I can't give you much direct help on this one, sorry. I've added the relevant tags to the question so hopefully someone interested in that topic will see the post.

Again thank you....I'm close...I think only another 30min...now once I solve this should I update my question with the fixed redirect or is that against stackoverflow rules..sorry

If you fix it, you should add an Answer below, the same way kalavainan has attempted to answer (but yours should hopefully contain a correct answer, and some explanation of what you changed, and why!). See also the [tour] if you need to understand the format of stackoverflow, and [answer] for answering tips. Certainly though you should not edit your question (above) with the solution - the answer is not part of the question, after all!

Again I'm not an expert on htaccess, but I suspect posts like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61530406/redirect-and-keep-the-parameter-in-the-url-on-htaccess might be helpful to you. You're aiming to preserve the OrdID query parameter which is in the original URL, and use it again in the new redirect URL. It looks like the RewriteCond directive can help you with that.

Thanks for the answer tip...will for sure do that...first attempt to fix failed...guess will be searching around on stackoverflow and will check your post link

If you make progress but it's still not quite right, you're fully at liberty to edit your question and post your latest attempt at modifying the htaccess. Then people can take a look and see if it just needs some correction

Great, thank you very much...again will explore more and will then edit my questions with everything I tried if unsuccessful

Fully understand if this gets downvoted as a very poor solution.
I just can't work out how to pass on the %{QUERY_STRING} so my poor but working solution is:
Added another redirect:
RewriteRule link--(.*)\--(.*)\--(.*)\--(.*)\--(.*)\--(.*)\--(.*)\.htm$ example.php?Vendor=$1&Maincategory=$2&Source=$3&Pos=$4&Search=$5&OrdID=$6&UserID=$7

Thanks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^link--([^/])--([^/])--([^/])--([^/])--([^/]*).htm$ example.php?Vendor=$1&Maincategory=$2&Source=$3&Pos=$4&Search=$5 [L]
Please try this
$OrdID=$_GET["OrdID"];

If (!empty($OrdID))
{
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","xxx","xxx");
mysql_select_db("xxx_Order", $con);
$query=mysql_query("Select Max(OrdID) FROM `Order`");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
$OrdID= $row[0] + 1;
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO `xxx_Order`.`Order` (`OrdID`) VALUES ($OrdID);"; 
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_close($con);
}


You're likely to get a more favourable response to your post if you take the time to explain your answer, including what you've done and why you expect that it solves the problem. Just dumping code is actually not very helpful most of the time. See also [answer]. Also, answers which reproduce obsolete / insecure code without acknowledgement or suggestion for improvement are not helpful to others. Thanks.

I don't think it is the "If (!empty($OrdID))"....just did an update and apologise for wasting everyones time...I think its my redirect

your url goes to html page how php code run @Richard

Sorry, not quite sure what you mean @kalaivanan
